# Noncrossing partitions in Hopf algebras/monoids via compositional inversion

Tags: co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, real-analysis, polynomials, hopf-algebras

Partition polynomials constructed from the face structures of the associahedra (OEIS [A133437](https://oeis.org/A133437)) and permutahedra ([A133314](https://oeis.org/A133314)) comprise the antipodes/compositional inverses in a Faa-di-Bruno-type Hopf monoid/algebra and a symmetric polynomial Hopf monoid/algebra, respectively (see [Aguilar and Ardila](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.07504), "Hopf monoids and generalized permutahedra"). Partition polynomials ([A134264](https://oeis.org/A134264)) constructed from the noncrossing partitions (NCPs) can also be used for compositional inversion. (All polytopes here and the NCPs are type A.)

**Question**: What role does this compositional inversion via the noncrossing partitions play in any Hopf monoids/algebras?

(Related discussions in "Hopf algebras and the logarithm of the S-transform in free probability" by [Mastnak and Nica](https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.4169), "Incidence Hopf algebras: Antipodes, forest formulas, and noncrossing partitions" by [Einziger](https://pqdtopen.proquest.com/doc/750317016.html?FMT=ABS), and "Operads of (noncrossing) partitions, interacting bialgebras, and moment-cumulant relations" by [Ebrahimi-Fard, Foissy, and Patras](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.01190).)

(Edit Sept. 19, 2019)

It would probably suffice to unwrap this observation I found in "Faa di Bruno Hopf Algebras" by [Figueroa](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0508337), Gracia-Bondia, and Varilly:

*Use of partitions with special properties may lead to other incidence algebras: for instance, if we restrict to noncrossing partitions, we obtain a cocommutative Hopf algebra, with the commutative group operation on characters essentially corresponding to Lagrange reversion of the Cauchy product of reverted series [cf. Stanley, Enumerative Comb., Vol. 2].*

(But, it would be enlightening to understand the role of NCPs in other Hopf algebras as well.)

Comment: Eqns. 6.27 on pg. 28 of Mastnak and Nica give an example of the NC polynomials $y_n$ that are the power series coefficients of the compositional inverse of $tH(-t)$ where $H(t)$ is the o.g.f. of the complete homogeneous symmetric polynomials.

Comment: Also "Hopf algebras and dendriform structures arising from parking functions" by Novelli, Thibon  https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0511200

Comment: And "Free cumulants, Schröder trees, and operads" by Josuat-Vergès, Menous, Novelli, and Thibon https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.04759

Comment: Also "The splitting process in free probability theory" by
Kurusch Ebrahimi-Fard, Frederic Patras https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.02748