# Intuitive, elementary intros to Hopf algebras/monoids

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, graph-theory, hopf-algebras

**Motivation**:

I'm interested in understanding the role that noncrossing partitions play in Hopf algebras/monoids (HAs) as the components of the power series of the compositional inverse of formal power series (or analytic functions at the origin, cf. OEIS [A134264](https://oeis.org/A134264)). The roles in HAs of the associahedra and permutahedra as delineating the combinatorics of compositional and multiplicative inversion are in encoding the antipodes in some HAs. I'm particularly interested in unwrapping this statement in Ref. 6 (Varilly et al.):

*Use of partitions with special properties may lead to other incidence algebras: for instance, if we restrict to noncrossing partitions, we obtain a cocommutative Hopf algebra, with the commutative group operation on characters essentially corresponding to Lagrange reversion of the Cauchy product of reverted series [cf. Stanley, Enumerative Comb., Vol. 2].*

(Cross-posted from MSE. Related [MO-Q](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/341684/noncrossing-partitions-in-hopf-algebras-monoids-via-compositional-inversion).)

**Request**:

To this end, I would like to understand the lingo and constructs of HAs at an elementary, intuitive level to build a stronger understanding and am seeking *free* pdf papers or books on the Web that discuss HAs in increasing generality with concrete examples.

Some that I'm already aware of are (in roughly increasing generality)

1) "Trees, renormalization, and diffetential equations" by C. Brouder

2) "A very basic introduction to Hopf algebras" by Selig

3) "Coalgebras and Bialgebras in Combinatorics" by
S. A. Joni  G.‐C. Rota

4) "Combinatorial Route to Algebra: The Art of Composition & Decomposition" by [Blasiak](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.4685)

5) "Hopf Algebras in General and in Combinatorial Physics: a practical introduction" by [Duchamp](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0508337), Blasiak, Horzela, Penson, and Solomon

6) "Faa di Bruno Hopf algebras" by [Figueroa](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0508337), Gracia-Bondia and Varilly

7) "Combinatorial Hopf algebras in quantum field theory I" by [Figueroa](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0408145) and Gracia-Bondia

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.8356

Comment: For the historical development, see "A primer of Hopf algebras" by Cartier http://preprints.ihes.fr/2006/M/M-06-40.pdf

Comment: @SamHopkins, I'm familiar with that set of notes, but view it as means of organizing one's knowledge of Hopf algebras and presenting it in an axiomatic fashion after one has mostly mastered applying the underlying notions and machinery in specific applications rather than as a means of obtaining that skill set--the historio-heuristic approach vs. the axiomatic approach / the Newton-Euler-Fourier-Riemann-Heaviside-Dirac-Feyman-Arnold vs the Cauchy-Weierstrass-Schwartz-Schwinger-Bourbaki approach.

Comment: Also see "Five interpretations of Faà di Bruno’s formula" by Alessandra Frabetti and Dominique Manchon (https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.5551)

Comment: And "Hopf Algebras: A Basic Introduction" by Kim (http://math.sjtu.edu.cn/conference/Bannai/2014/data/20141213C/slides.pdf)

Comment: Motivational: "Hopf algebras: their status and pervasiveness" (as of Oct. 2004) by Hazewinkel (https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0411536)

Comment: Also see "Hopf algebras in dynamical systems theory" by Carinena,  Ebrahimi-Fard, Figueroa, and Gracia-Bondıa https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701010

Comment: Related MO-Q: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84161/hopf-algebras-examples/84163#84163

Comment: For a physicist, via differential operators, Quantum Field Theory ll: Quantum Electrodynamics by Zeidler.

Comment: "Umbral Calculus and Hopf Algebras" by Robert Morris contains "Coalgebras and Bialgebras in Combinatorics" by Rota and Joni and "Hopf Algebras and Combinatorics" by Nichols and Sweedler (a good intro to the standard notation).

Comment: "Hopf algebras: motivations and examples" by Duchamp, Blasiak, Horzela, Penson, and Solomon